# How do I create a vector for XPages REST service startKeys?

Tags: xpages

I have a view sorted on the first column by noteid

I want to use the ExtLib REST service startKeys parameter to match specific values from that list.

I see from the description that a vector is required, but the following code does not work - why not?

```
<xe:this.startKeys>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var vec:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
        var temp = 'NT0000BD22'
        vec.add(temp);                      
        temp = 'NT0000BD29'
        vec.add(temp);                      
        return vec
    }]]>
</xe:this.startKeys>
```

The error returned form the server states: 
{
    "code":400,
    "text":"Bad Request",
    "message":"Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector",
    "type":"text",
    "data":"com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException: \r\n\tat

Comment: Marky,  maybe try adding angle brackets in your Vector definition.  In pure java it would look like Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();
Of course you will need to make it work in SSJS java, I don't think I have ever used angle brackets in SSJS so I can only guess that they are supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property `startKeys` of `xe:viewJsonService` does work only for one key. It is the key **from where** the view rows get delivered from REST service. You can't pick certain keys from view and get delivered only those rows this way.

Property `startKeys` with more then one key is useful if you have a view with more then one sorted column. Then first key has to match first sorted column, second key has to match second sorted column and so on.

There seems to be an issue with Vector for `startKeys` in `xe:viewJsonService` though. Your code works for `xp:dominoView` (if you use startKeys as described in paragraph before) but not for `xe:viewJsonService`. It does work for `keys` in `xe:viewJsonService` too which you should use anyway to get exactly the rows for a certain key.

Comment: Ah even if it were to work coreectly it will not return what I want what is two matches. It is supposed to match multiple  sub categories. Thanks :)